# Codificación en Proxy inverso apache

Tags: apache, proxy

Tengo una intranet en la codificación ISO-8859-1, y una aplicación en UTF-8, que debe colgar de esta intranet.

He configurado el proxy en apache, como puedes ver abajo, todo funciona correctamente excepto la codificación, alguna sugerencia??

Gracias de antemano.

```
<Location /myapp/>                
ProxyPass   http://www.urlmyapp.es/
ProxyPassReverse        http://www.urlmyapp.es/

SetOutputFilter         INFLATE;proxy-html;DEFLATE
RequestHeader           unset Accept-Encoding

AddDefaultCharset       utf-8
Header set Content-Type "text/html; charset=utf-8"
AddCharset              uft-8 .htm .html .js .css .text .php

ProxyHTMLEnable         On
ProxyHTMLExtended       On

ProxyHTMLURLMap         ^/(assets/.*)   /myapp/$1      [R]

ProxyHTMLInterp         On
ProxyHTMLFixups         dospath
ProxyHTMLLinks          a       href
ProxyHTMLLinks          area    href
ProxyHTMLLinks          link    href
ProxyHTMLLinks          img     src longdesc usemap
ProxyHTMLLinks          object  classid codebase data usemap
ProxyHTMLLinks          q       cite
ProxyHTMLLinks          blockquote      cite
ProxyHTMLLinks          ins     cite
ProxyHTMLLinks          del     cite
ProxyHTMLLinks          form    action
ProxyHTMLLinks          input   src usemap
ProxyHTMLLinks          head    profile
ProxyHTMLLinks          base    href
ProxyHTMLLinks          script  src for
ProxyHTMLLinks          iframe  src
ProxyHTMLLinks          frame   src
ProxyHTMLLinks          body    background
ProxyHTMLLinks          option  value
ProxyHTMLEvents onclick ondblclick      onmousedown     onmouseup \
onmouseover onmousemove onmouseout onkeypress \
onkeydown onkeyup onfocus onblur onload \
onunload onsubmit onreset onselect onchange
```